# Remove extra prompts in inferior-python-mode with ipython

Tags: python, ipython, prompt

1. `emacs24.5 -Q`
2. <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")` <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `run-python` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015, 12:58:09) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: 
In [2]: 
In [3]: 
In [4]:
```

This may seem pretty insignificant, but I honestly believe that small cosmetic quirks like these can have a large impression on those who do not already love Emacs. And besides, I'm OCD. :)

Comment: Same thing happens with  normal interpreter too, it prints `>>> >>> >>> >>> 
` at the beginning.

Comment: @ChillarAnand, really? It doesn't do it for me in `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Weird, don't know why its happening. Demo: https://goo.gl/HZy3RB

Comment: @ChillarAnand I don't know what's going on. I just fired up a Fedora VM, and Emacs behaves like in your video. I normally use Arch. :/